# Jupyter notebook gets disconnected and I risk losing my work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

My Jupyter Kernel got disconnected. I followed the necessary steps and relaunched it, without closing the original tab. However, that file has not been updated in the new launch. The original tab is still showing an error. What do I do so that I can keep working in a notebook that works without losing my previous work?

Comment: Look for a folder called `.ipynb_checkpoints/` in the same folder as your notebook. You should have an auto-saved copy of your notebook there.

Comment: Did you try to figure out why your kernel dies?

Comment: @foglerit could not find it there. However, I realized I could just save that file with a different name and it would still get lodged into the system

Comment: @user206904 na not really. Any idea why? Most people say it's because the notebook version is outdated

Comment: that's probably not the reason... When you lunch jupyter-notebook from the command line normally the kernel messages are displayed, when the kernel dies head back to your terminal and check the kernel log displayed there.